# Error in uploading image into mysql database

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I've been trying to solve this error for hours. Can anyone help me where is the mistake? Thanks. I was trying to upload an image into mysql database. Php error log direct me the error: Undefined Index uploadedfile. Thanks!

test.php

```
    Flavor: <input id="flavor" type="text" name="flavor">
    Upload image: <input type="file" name="uploadedfile" id="uploadedfile" />
```

this is my codes:

```
<?php
include_once "mysqli.connect.php";

if(isset($_POST['Add']))
{       
        $flavor = $_POST['flavor'];
        $target_path = "images/";
        $image = basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
        $target_path = $target_path . $image;


        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) 
        {

            $sql = "INSERT INTO flavor (flavorname, image) VALUES('$flavor','$target_path')";   
            $result = $mysqli->query($sql);     
            echo"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Flavor added!')</script>";           
        }
        else
        {
            echo"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Error! Can't proceed.' )</script>";  
        }

        }       
?>
```

Comment: check for `isset($_FILES)` before uploading

Comment: You are vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks! Learn about prepared statements to defend yourself!

Comment: form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="__URL__" method="POST">....

Comment: Thanks @ZigZag! I forgotten to add form enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually uploading your files into database.
And whole problem has nothing to do with databases at all.

So, to make your upload work, make sure you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute in your form.
Refer to the [manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) for the related info.